# how to pass dictionary to test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am quite new in the writing of tests (for python) and so I have now the question how can I pass a dictionary to a test-function? At the moment I do the following:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
from app.views import file_io
import pytest
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import codecs

@pytest.fixture()
def tempdir():
    tempdir = mkdtemp()
    yield tempdir
    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)

articles = [
        ["", "README.md", "# Hallo Welt", "<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>\n"],
        ["test", "article.md", "# Hallo Welt", "<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>\n"]
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("dir, file, content_plain, content_md", articles)
def test_readRaw(tempdir, dir, file, content_plain, content_md):
    dest_path=os.path.join(tempdir, dir)
    os.makedirs(dest_path, exist_ok=True)

    with codecs.open(os.path.join(dest_path, file), 'w', 'utf-8') as fh:
        fh.write(content_plain)

    assert file_io.readRaw(os.path.join(dest_path, file)) == content_plain
```

and my idea/hope is that I could modify the code so I can do something like:

```
articles = [
               { "dir": "",
                 "filename": "README.md",
                 "content_md": "# Hello World",
                 "content_html": "<h1>Hello World</h1>\n" },
               { "dir": "test",
                 "filename": "article.md",
                 "content_md": "# Hallo Welt",
                 "content_html": "<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>\n"}

]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(**articles, articles)
def test_readRaw(tempdir, **articles):
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(dir, file), 'w', 'utf-8') as fh:
        fh.write(content_md)

    assert file_io.readRaw(os.path.join(dir, file)) == content_md
```

especially I would like to avoid the mentioning of all keys so I can extend the dictionary if I miss something without modified all tests.

Maybe this is is a silly question but as I say I am just beginning with this topic and so I would very thanksful for every a hint how can I do this (or what is a better way).
best regards
Dan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of trying to splat / unsplat, try taking `article` as a parameter:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('article', articles)
def test_readRaw(tempdir, article):
    # use `article['foo']` here...
```

Another option (utilizing python3.6+ features) is to expand the keys manually -- though you have to be careful that you define each of the dictionaries in the same order

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(tuple(articles[0]), [tuple(dct.values()) for dct in articles])
def test_readRaw(tempdir, dir, file, content_plain, content_md):
    ...
```

for what it's worth, I think you'd be sacrificing some readability (and making the test particularly fragile) by taking the second approach

---

~related advice

- you can use the built in [`tmp_path` / `tmpdir` fixtures](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) instead of building your own
- your function-under-test doesn't actually depend on `dir` or `file`, you'd be better off not parametrizing these

taking both of those into account, your test becomes much simpler to do with classic parametrization (a simple table of inputs / outputs):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ('content_plain', 'content_md'),
    (
        ("# Hallo Welt", "<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>\n"),
        ("# ohai", "<h1>ohai</h1>\n"),
    ),
)
def test_readRaw(tmpdir, content_plain, content_md):
    f = tmpdir.join('f')
    f.write(content_plain)
    assert file_io.readRaw(f) == content_md
```

---

disclaimer: I'm one of the current core devs on `pytest`

Comment: I want to implement the first solution, but in my case articles is a dictionary that is returned by importing the fixture function from conftest. I get the following error: `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and I used @anthony sottile's first answer, but unpacked it in the test directly:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("articles", articles)
def test_readRaw(tempdir, articles: dict):
    (dir, filename, content_md, content_html) = articles.values()
```

In case someone comes along and needs the same solution.